# Django reverse causing url circular import, why?

Tags: django, django-urls

I get this error:

> The included urlconf 'fouraxis.urls' does not appear to have any
>   patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue
>   is probably caused by a circular import.

I know the url pattern has something in it, it looks like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^perfil/', include('clientes.urls'), namespace="cliente"),
        url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
    ]
```

clientes.urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

from clientes import views

urlpatterns = [
        # login
        url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'perfiles/login.html'}, name="login"),
        url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'template_name': 'perfiles/logged_out.html'}, name="login"),

        url(r'^mi_perfil/$', views.mi_perfil, name="mi_perfil"),
        url(r'^registro_usuario/$', views.RegistroUsuario.as_view(), name="registro_usuario")
    ]
```

The RegistroUsuario view looks like this:

```
class RegistroUsuario(FormView):
    template_name = "perfiles/registro_usuario.html"
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse("cliente:mi_perfil")  # THIS REVERSE

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return redirect("cliente:mi_perfil")

    context = {'form': UserCreationForm}
```

I understand I can replace the `reverse` with a plain-text url like this `perfil/mi_perfil`. But, I want to know why is this happening with reverse, I can't find the explanation on de docs. Also, using reverse is better cause it is dynamic (if anytime I change the url, it still works as long as it keeps its name).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `reverse()` call is made when the view is imported, which is probably when the urlconf is first loaded. You need to use `reverse_lazy()` instead:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy

class RegistroUsuario(FormView):
    template_name = "perfiles/registro_usuario.html"
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy("cliente:mi_perfil")  # THIS REVERSE

    def form_valid(self, form):
        return redirect("cliente:mi_perfil")

    context = {'form': UserCreationForm}
```

Comment: Thanks, `reverse_lazy` is the solution. So.. urlconf is not loaded yet when the view is imported?

Comment: You import the view in your urlconf... so no.

Comment: For Django 2.0+, replace `django.core.urlresolvers` with `django.urls`.